# There is no json.h in \usr\include\json-c directory ' ../nvme.h:26:10: fatal error: json.h: No such file or directory'

Tags: c, json, ubuntu-18.04, nvme, json-c

There is no "json.h" in "\usr\include\json-c" directory. Is there an application that I have to install? I have installed "sudo apt-get install libjsoncpp-dev," but it is not working.

```
ubuntu@nvme-cli:~/nvme-cli$ ninja -C .build
ninja: Entering directory `.build'
[1/29] Compiling C object nvme.p/fabrics.c.o
FAILED: nvme.p/fabrics.c.o 
cc -Invme.p -I. -I.. -Iccan -I../ccan -I/usr/include/json-c -I/usr/include/uuid 
-fdiagnostics -color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -std=gnu99 -O3 
-fomit-frame-pointer -D_GNU_SOURCE -include config.h -MD -MQ 
nvme.p/fabrics.c.o -MF nvme.p/fabrics.c.o.d -o nvme.p/fabrics.c.o -c ../fabrics.c
In file included from ../fabrics.c:41:0:
../nvme.h:26:10: fatal error: json.h: No such file or directory
 #include <json.h>
          ^~~~~~~~


compilation terminated.
[2/29] Compiling C object nvme.p/plugins_intel_intel-nvme.c.o
FAILED: nvme.p/plugins_intel_intel-nvme.c.o 
cc -Invme.p -I. -I.. -Iccan -I../ccan -I/usr/include/json-c -I/usr/include/uuid 
-fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -std=gnu99 -O3 
-fomit-frame-pointer -D_GNU_SOURCE -include config.h -MD -MQ 
nvme.p/plugins_intel_intel-nvme.c.o -MF nvme.p/plugins_intel_intel-nvme.c.o.d -o nvme.p/plugins_intel_intel-nvme.c.o -c ../plugins/intel/intel-nvme.c
In file included from ../plugins/intel/intel-nvme.c:9:0:
../nvme.h:26:10: fatal error: json.h: No such file or directory
 #include <json.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

I have installed libjson-c-dev package and it solved the problem.

```
sudo apt install libjson-c-dev
```